# Keyframes animation - Firefox won't change background gradient

Tags: css, firefox, gradient, css-animations

So I'm making this pulsing gradient thingy for my friends Tumblr page. Here's the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nippon/yYteE/

and part of the code (@keyframes are too long to post here):

```
.animate {
-moz-animation: color 14s infinite linear;
-o-animation: color 14s infinite linear;
-webkit-animation: color 14s infinite linear;
animation: color 14s infinite linear;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I've used http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for generating gradients. Transparent color is a must, but I don't think setting solid white will change anything.

The problem is that the animation is working as indented only in Chrome & IE10.
Firefox animates only opacity and gradient always stays the same (default turquoise).

I was trying to fix that by removing *-moz-* prefixes and adding *!important* but still no luck.

Comment: Try using a simpler gradient properties. I'm not sure if firefox really supports gradient fades but you might want to give it a go.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients

Comment: Inspired by some stackflow answers in other threads regarding this problem I've re-done the whole thing. It's easier to modify, smaller and it's working in FF now:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nippon/rHj9H/

Comment: I've separated each colour to different layer and I'm just animating layers opacity. Details are in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I've found similar problem in other thread and I came up with quite simple solution/workaround.

It's smaller, less complicated and easier to modify since you don't have to copy/paste background regarding lines to every keyframe and it's working in Chrome, FireFox, Opera and IE10.

So, every colour becomes separate layer and you just have to synchronize layers opacity in animation, for example 3 colours fading and mixing:

```
@keyframes turk {
0% {opacity:0.8;}
17% {opacity:0.4;}
34% {opacity:0;}
51% {opacity:0;}
68% {opacity:0;}
85% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:0.8;}
}
@keyframes yell {
0% {opacity:0;}
17% {opacity:0;}
34% {opacity:0.8;}
51% {opacity:0.4;}
68% {opacity:0;}
85% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes pinky {
0% {opacity:0;}
17% {opacity:0;}
34% {opacity:0;}
51% {opacity:0;}
68% {opacity:0.8;}
85% {opacity:0.4;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

Check out demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/Nippon/rHj9H/